# Adding version number on Xamarin.iOS Splash screen

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

Anyone has an idea how can I update the label and put a version number on there so that I don't need it to write manually every time I publish the new version on iOS. Please download my sample project in this link [Splashscreen with version number](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14EW6hnUuPHhX3TfdR_0tOpooGn5_x_AA).

I try to add UIViewController to use it on Storyboard but it's not working.

Comment: You could set the UIViewController  as rootViewController firstly to show the info , and change rootViewController as  another ViewController after the delay .

Comment: I already tried that, after assigning the UIViewController class to storyboard, the class was not triggered.

Comment: Post the code will be helpful to solve the issue .

Answer (score 1):

first thing, it is not possible to provide dynamic value on the launch screen which comes as a default view with the IOS project.
you have to create your own splashscreen by storyboard so you will have viewcontroller code behind and there you can do whatever the details you want to display. you can show the animation also there.

you have to set this splashviewcontroller as a rootviewcontroller in finishlaunching() of appdelegate.

check below code:- try something like this.

public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }
  public RootViewController RootViewController { get; set; }

```
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions){
     this.Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
     UINavigationController navigationController = new 
     UINavigationController(new SplashViewController());
     Window.RootViewController = navigationController;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I cannot download your code for security reasons on my network, but In Xamarin.iOS, You can get the version number from the info.plist then set your label text to the value. This way as you update the version for releases the label will automatically reflect the current version number.

```
var appVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"].ToString();

lblAppVersion.Text = appVersion;
```

Comment: My problem was where I can update the  "lblAppVersion.Text" value without having ViewController in my storyboard? Or If not possible without ViewController, How can I add ViewController for Storyboard because when I add ViewController class and assigned it to Storyboard as a class, the ViewController was not trigger